# there exists k such that all elements of A^k are positive iff G is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

How we can prove this:
Suppose G is a connected graph with adjacent matrix A. prove that there exists k such that all elements of $A^k$ are positive iff G is bipartite. Is $A^n > 0$ if G is not bipartite? 
$(n = |V(G)|)$

I have a question. one side from 1 to 2 is easy. but for the other side, as we know, ij th  $A^k$ element show number of walks of length k between vertexes $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$. So it's not clear for me that why there should exist walk between each two vertices? Because the meaning of question is this.
Would you please help me for proving this problem?
thanks

Comment: I think you've got the question wrong. For instance, if the graph is bipartite, then the length of paths from one component to the other is odd, and those to from the component to itself is even, so there is *no* k such that A^k has all positive elements. However, even not ebeing bipartite is no guarantee: a graph with six edges and vertices making two disjoint cycles of size 3 cannot be made bipartite, nor can its adjacency matrix have positive powers.

Comment: True, @user, but your second example isn't connected; the question asks about connected graphs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, yes. In which case, I think the hypothesis "Suppose $G$ is a connected graph with adjacent matrix $A$. There exists k such that all elements of $A^k$ are positive iff G is *not* bipartite" is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove "Suppose $G$ is a connected graph with adjacent matrix $A$. There exists k such that all elements of $A^k$ are positive iff G is *not* bipartite"

Firstly, if $G$ is bipartite and $v$ and $w$ are in the same vertex set, after partitioning, then there are no odd length paths between $v$ and $w$, whereas if they are in different partitions, then there are no even length paths between them. Therefore, as $G$ is connected, there will be some integer $N$ such that for all $k>N$, $A^k$ will be non zero precisely where $A^{k+1}$ is zero, and neither will be entirely non zero.

Secondly, if $G$ is not bipartite, then there is a loop $l_0, l_1, \ldots, l_{2n}, l_{2n+1} = l_0$ such that $(l_i, l_{i+1})$ is an edge for all $0\leq i\leq 2n.$ As $G$ is connected, given vertices $v$ and $w$, there is a path $P_v$ from $v$ to $l_0$ of length $m_1$ and a path $P_w$ from $w$ to $l_n$ of length $m_2$.

I claim that there is path of length $N$ from $v$ to $w$ for all $N \geq m_1 + m_2 + n$. To see this observe there is a path of length $m_1 + m_2 + n$ obtained by traversing $P_v$, then the slightly shorter half of the loop from $l_0$ to $l_n$ and then traversing $P_w$ in reverse. Similarly, there is a path of length $m_1 + m_2 + n + 1$ obtained in the same way, but traversing the long half of the loop in reverse to get from $l_0$ to $l_n$. Every other length is then obtained by inserting copies of the path from $l_0, l_1, l_0$ into one or other of these paths at the end of $P_v$.

This is a bit notationally lazy, but the ideas are there.